# Android - Read image using opencv

Tags: android, image, opencv, highgui

I tried reading an image from **drawable** folder. I am using **eclipse** ide. I ran the below code but the image was not loaded. The code is taken from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/42025/reading-an-image-from-drawable-folder-android/)

```
Mat image =  new Mat(new Size(500,500 ),CvType.CV_8U);// Change CvType as you need.
            image = Highgui.imread("icon.png");
            if(image.empty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Empty image!");
            }
```

My 
Screenshot of my drawable folder is below : 
[image]

How can I load this image?

Comment: Please tell if Highgui has a method to read from an inputstream. If so, you could open a stream like this: `getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon)`. Or maybe Highgui can read from resources?

Comment: I don't understand that how I can use getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon) with Highgui.imread function.

Comment: Not with `imread()` of course. That's why i asked you `Please tell if Highgui has a method to read from an inputstream.`. So why didn't you answer my question? You can easily get a list of all available functions for Highgui in the IDE.

Comment: Highgui loads image using only `imread()` function. There is no another function for this.

Comment: Well than you have to copy your icon from the drawable resource to the file system as file. Then use that file.

Comment: Probably I should use `openRawResource` via `InputStream inpT = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.img);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example for this work.

```
InputStream inpT = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.imgt);
mTemp = readInputStreamIntoMat(inpT);

private static Mat readInputStreamIntoMat(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // Read into byte-array
    byte[] temporaryImageInMemory = readStream(inputStream);

    // Decode into mat. Use any IMREAD_ option that describes your image appropriately
    Mat outputImage = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfByte(temporaryImageInMemory), Highgui.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    return outputImage;
}

private static byte[] readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    // Copy content of the image to byte-array
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((nRead = stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    byte[] temporaryImageInMemory = buffer.toByteArray();
    buffer.close();
    stream.close();
    return temporaryImageInMemory;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just simply do this

```
Mat m = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.img, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.cols(), m.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(m, bm);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: @zumma this should be the correct answer. But: Highgui is not available on Android. It's been split into separate packages ("videoio" and "imgcodecs"). But you can also use `Utils.loadResource(Context, int)`

Comment: @muetzenflo I fixed the call. Hopefully Zain won't be angry because of that

Answer (score 0):

should be doing instead is:

```
  Mat m = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I tried it, but it cannot loaded. My code is : 'Mat image =  new Mat(new Size(500,500 ),CvType.CV_8U);// Change CvType as you need.

             File file = new File("icon.png");
          image = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
          if(image.empty()) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Empty image!");
          }'